# Excel filter based on entity maximum

Tags: excel, filter

I have a large number of records, which look like this:

```
Name    Value
E        10
A        2
D        4
E        10
A        5
B        3
B        10
D        10
C        4
```

I am trying to filter this table based on the following logic:
Select all records for those `names` for which the maximum value is not larger than 5. Based on the above example, I would select all records for names A and C, because their maxima are 5 and 3 respectively:

```
Name    Value
A        2
A        5
C        4
```

B, D and E will be excluded, because their maxima are 10 (for each of them).

1. Is there a way to do this with pivot tables ?
2. If it's not possible using pivot tables, there a way to do this using formulae, without reverting to VBA ?

I know how to create a `MAXIF`UDF, and use it in filtering, but I am trying to avoid that for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C2** enter the array formula:

```
=IF(MAX(IF(A$2:A$9999=A2,B$2:B$9999))>5,"",1)
```

and copy down.  Then filter by column **C**

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: I think you need to add absolute references to the A$1:A$999 and B$1:B$999 ranges before filling the whole column. Otherwise it works fine, thanks a lot!